# Add an if inside apply in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the following function:

```
d["direction"] = d.apply(lambda x: 180 + 180/(m.pi*(m.atan2(x.water_u,x.water_v))), axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

The function adds a column named direction based on the calculation of 2 columns water_u and water_v - As you can see if the angle is zero there will be a zero-division and therefore an error, now I can make a function to add an if, such that it is zero the value of the division remains zero but is there a pythonic way to do this inside my lambda function?

Anyway, I would be grateful, if someone knows a smart succinct way to achieve this.

Regards

Comment: Use the conditional operator: `val1 if condition else val2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `lambda` function.

Compute your angle separately and use `np.where` to compute the direction or not:

```
import numpy as np

angle = (np.pi*(np.arctan2(df.water_u, df.water_v)))
df['direction'] = np.where(angle != 0, 180 + 180 / angle, 0)
```

Example:

```
# Before
>>> df
   water_u  water_v
0        0        0
1       10       20

# After
>>> df
   water_u  water_v   direction
0        0        0    0.000000
1       10       20  303.576135
```